# Script/software to search text in lots of script files in a folder

Tags: search

I want to search a word in lots of script files

It may linux software or script

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a superuser.com question than a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

`man grep`

And read that. Then checkout `man sed` and `man awk` and have a peek at Perl.  It is **essential to know these things** on Unix-like systems!

Answer (score 0):

Next time, provide more info. with that said, you can try tools like grep, or awk with combination of find.

```
grep -r "word" *
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a small shell script, which will print the number of occurrences of your search phrase in each file:

```
for file in `ls`; 
do 
    printf '%-50s' "$file"; 
    grep -c "SEARCH PHRASE HERE"
done
```

Which would give something like:

```
misc.rst                                          0
database_sources.rst                              0
postgis_cookbook.rst                              21
data_sources.rst                                  14
...
```

To find the occurrences of the phrase in each file, use `cat` and `grep` together:

```
cat -n filename | grep "SEARCH PHRASE HERE"
```

This would give you the lines in the file in which the phrase appears. The `-n` argument gives you the lines with numbers, for easy finding.

Comment: grep -c "SEARCH PHRASE HERE" * is much shorter than all your above.  also you do not properly handle multiple occurrences on one line.

Comment: replaced to grep -c, thanks. Since the question was abound finding the words, not the number of occurrences, I think it would suffice - especially if using cat and grep afterwards.